# Infinite renders when i put any element in dependency array functional component react

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, use-effect, use-state

I want my states to update after **useEffect**, yes I tried the **dependency array** method but whenever I put something in it, the component **render infinite time**. I want it to update the state only the two main I want **roles and userRoles** to get update, rest component will work fine if these two will get updated

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import WmTextbox from "components/basic/forms/WmTextbox";
import WmCheckbox from "components/basic/forms/WmCheckbox";
import WmFormError from "components/basic/forms/WmFormError";
import WmFormErrorMessage from "components/basic/forms/WmFormErrorMessage";
import { isNullOrEmpty, isNullOrUndefined } from "common/Utilities";
import { PlusOutlined, CloseOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Checkbox } from "antd";
import {
  require,
  minLength,
  compare,
  email,
} from "common/forms/WmFormValidators.js";
import WmButtonPrimary from "components/basic/buttons/WmButtonPrimary.js";
import { accountService } from "services/AccountService.js";
import { roleService } from "services/RoleService";
import WmList from "src/components/basic/list/WmList";
import { wmMessage } from "components/basic/notifications/WmMessage.js";
import { useForms } from "common/hooks/WmHooks.js";
import {
  useRedirect,
  useDocTitle,
  useComponentMounted,
} from "common/hooks/WmHooks.js";

const UpdateUser = (props) => {
  const params = props.params;
  const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);
  const [userRoles, setUserRoles] = useState([]);
  const [userSelectedList, setUserSelectedList] = useState([]);
  const [userSelectedCheckbox, setUserSelectedCheckbox] = useState([]);
  const [showModulesList, setShowModulesList] = useState(false);
  
  const [wmForms] = useForms([
    {
      name: "username",
      value: "",
      validators: [
        { name: "require", func: require },
        { name: "minLength", func: minLength, param: { minLength: 3 } },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "email",
      value: "",
      validators: [
        { name: "require", func: require },
        { name: "email", func: email },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "firstName",
      value: "",
      validators: [{ name: "require", func: require }],
    },
    {
      name: "lastName",
      value: "",
      validators: [{ name: "require", func: require }],
    },
    {
      name: "active",
      value: "",
      resetValue: true,
      validators: [],
    },
  ]);

  const update = async () => {
    if (wmForms.validate()) {
      const model = wmForms.toModel();
      // console.log(model);
      try {
        const response = await accountService.update(params.id, model);
        wmMessage.success("User updated");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        wmMessage.error(error.response.data.result);
      }
    }
  };

  const getById = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await accountService.getById(id);
      const objUser = response.data.result;
      return objUser;
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  
  const setForm = (obj) => {
    wmForms.setFormValue("username", obj.username);
    wmForms.setFormValue("email", obj.email);
    wmForms.setFormValue("firstName", obj.firstName);
    wmForms.setFormValue("lastName", obj.lastName);
    wmForms.setFormValue("active", obj.active);
    setUserRoles(rolesFromDb=>obj.roles);
    updateUserSelectedList(obj.roles);
    updateUserSelectedCheckbox(obj.roles)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    useDocTitle("Update Users");
    console.log("Im running in useEffect" , roles)
    getRoles().then(()=>{
      console.log('roles component mount', roles)
      if (props.data != null) {
        setForm(props.data);
      } else {
        getById(params.id).then((res) => {
          setForm(res);
        });
      }
    })
  },[]);
  const getRoles = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await roleService.getAll();
      let allRoles = response.data.result;
      console.log('all roles', allRoles)
      setRoles(allRoles);
    } catch (error) {
      wmMessage.error(error);
    }
  };

  const updateUserSelectedCheckbox = (selectedRoles) => {
    console.log('se;e', selectedRoles)
    const selectedRoleWithName = [];
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(selectedRoles)) {
      // selectedRoles.map((rol, i) => {
      //   roles.map((r, j) => {
      //     const id = r._id;
      //     if (rol.roleId === id) {
      //       let obj = {
      //         value: id,
      //         label: r.title,
      //       };
      //       console.log('I got pushed')
      //       selectedRoleWithName.push(obj);
      //     }
      //   });
      // });
      console.log("userRoles",userRoles)
      _.forEach(selectedRoles,role =>{
        _.forEach(userRoles,sRole=>{
          if(role.roleId === sRole._id){
            selectedRoleWithName.push({
              value:sRole._id,
              label: role.title
            })
          }
        })
      })
      console.log(selectedRoleWithName, "selectedRoleWithName")
      setUserSelectedList(selectedRoleWithName);
    }
  };

  const getStandardizeRolesforCheckboxList = () => {
    let rolesData = [];
    if (roles.length > 0) {
      roles.map((mod) => {
        let obj = { value: mod._id, label: mod.title };
        rolesData.push(obj);
      });
    }
    return rolesData;
  };

  const handleModuleChangeCheckbox = (roleIds) => {
    console.log('roleIds', roleIds)
    const selectedRoles = [];
    roleIds.map((rolId) => {
      let m = { roleId: rolId };
      selectedRoles.push(m);
    });
    updateUserRoles(selectedRoles);
    updateUserSelectedList(selectedRoles);
    updateUserSelectedCheckbox(selectedRoles);
  };

  const handleOnDeleteModule = (id) => {
    const selectedModules = [];
    console.log(userRoles, id)
    userRoles.map((rol) => {
      if (rol.roleId !== id) {
        let m = { roleId: rol.roleId };
        selectedModules.push(m);
      }
    });
  };

  const updateUserSelectedList = (checkedRoles) => {
    console.log(checkedRoles,"Im in listing")
    const selectedRole = [];
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(checkedRoles)) {
      checkedRoles.map((rol) => {
        selectedRole.push(rol.roleId);
      });
    }
    setUserSelectedCheckbox([...selectedRole]);
  };

  const updateUserRoles = async (data) => {
    console.log('updateUserRoles', data);
    const putData = {roles: data};
    try {
      console.log('sddsfd', await accountService.updateUserRole(params.id, putData));
      
    } catch (err) {
      wmMessage.error(err);
    }
  };

  const prepareDisplayListData = (leftData, leftDataKey) => {
    console.log('left right roles', roles)
    // const selected = [];
    // if (!isNullOrUndefined(leftData)) {
    //   leftData.map((l, i) => {
    //     rightData.map((r, j) => {
    //       const id = r._id;
    //       if (l[leftDataKey] === id) {
    //         let obj = {
    //           value: id,
    //           label: r.title,
    //         };
    //         selected.push(obj);
    //       }
    //     });
    //   });
    // }
    // return selected;
    //setSelectedDisplayRoleIDWithName(selected);
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-8">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Username</label>
          <WmTextbox
            className="form-control"
            value={wmForms.getFormValue("username")}
            formName="username"
            wmForms={wmForms}
            disabled={true}
          />
          <div>
            <WmFormError
              wmForms={wmForms}
              formName="username"
              validator="require"
            >
              <WmFormErrorMessage>Username is required</WmFormErrorMessage>
            </WmFormError>
          </div>
          <div>
            <WmFormError
              wmForms={wmForms}
              formName="username"
              validator="minLength"
            >
              <WmFormErrorMessage>
                Username must be at least 3 characters
              </WmFormErrorMessage>
            </WmFormError>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <WmTextbox
            className="form-control"
            value={wmForms.getFormValue("email")}
            formName="email"
            wmForms={wmForms}
            disabled={true}
          />
          <div>
            <WmFormError wmForms={wmForms} formName="email" validator="require">
              <WmFormErrorMessage>Email is required</WmFormErrorMessage>
            </WmFormError>
          </div>
          <div>
            <WmFormError wmForms={wmForms} formName="email" validator="email">
              <WmFormErrorMessage>Invalid email</WmFormErrorMessage>
            </WmFormError>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>First name</label>
          <WmTextbox
            className="form-control"
            value={wmForms.getFormValue("firstName")}
            formName="firstName"
            wmForms={wmForms}
          />
          <div>
            <WmFormError
              wmForms={wmForms}
              formName="firstName"
              validator="require"
            >
              <WmFormErrorMessage>First name is required</WmFormErrorMessage>
            </WmFormError>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Last name</label>
          <WmTextbox
            className="form-control"
            value={wmForms.getFormValue("lastName")}
            formName="lastName"
            wmForms={wmForms}
          />
          <div>
            <WmFormError
              wmForms={wmForms}
              formName="lastName"
              validator="require"
            >
              <WmFormErrorMessage>Last name is required</WmFormErrorMessage>
            </WmFormError>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="input-group mb-4">
          <WmCheckbox
            checked={wmForms.getFormValue("active")}
            formName="active"
            wmForms={wmForms}
          >
            Active
          </WmCheckbox>
        </div>
        <div>
          <WmButtonPrimary onClick={update}>Update</WmButtonPrimary>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-4">
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white", padding: "20px" }}>
              {showModulesList ? (
                <div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-8" style={{ color: "grey" }}>
                      SELECT Roles
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-4" id="align-right">
                      <div>
                        <span onClick={() => setShowModulesList(false)}>
                          <CloseOutlined style={{ color: "blue" }} />
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                      <Checkbox.Group
                        options={getStandardizeRolesforCheckboxList()}
                        defaultValue={userSelectedCheckbox}
                        onChange={handleModuleChangeCheckbox}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-8" style={{ color: "#4582f5" }}>
                      Roles
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-4" id="align-right">
                      <div>
                        <span onClick={() => setShowModulesList(true)}>
                          <PlusOutlined style={{ color: "#4582f5" }} />
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12" id="module-list">
                      <WmList
                        datasource={userSelectedList}
                        onDelete={handleOnDeleteModule}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UpdateUser;
```

Comment: if you adding a dependency in useEffect and setting that state in useEffect, it creates infinite loop

Comment: Im calling a function from useEffect that update a state, if I add that in dependency array it go infinite, is there any solution for it?

Comment: try useCallback

Comment: Consider to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in combination with a [React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) to get more/better answers.